# Struts2 same action name for post and get

Tags: post, struts2, get, action

I want to use an action (UserAction) to handle multiple form (such as : login, register). When i redirect to action, it return form view. When i submit form, it post data to action and then return view.
If i use ASP.NET MVC, i can put annotation to classify post and get method like

```
public class UserAction extends ActionSupport {
  [HttpGet]
  public String login() {
     return "login";
  }
  [HttpPost]
  public String login() {
     return "login";
  }

  [HttpGet]
  public String register() {
      return "register";
  } 

  [HttpPost]
  public String register() {
      return "register";
  } 
}
```

I don't want use two method name for one form like

```
 public class UserAction extends ActionSupport {
  public String getLogin() {
     return "login";
  }

  public String postLogin() {
     return "login";
  }    

  public String getRegister() {
      return "register";
  }       

  public String postRegister() {
      return "register";
  } 
}
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: I don't understand the question; there's no automatic differentiation between GET and POST requests because the processing is almost never different. If they're returning the same results you only need one method. If your question is actually how do I have a GET method to return the form, and a POST method to *process* that form, there's nothing out-of-the-box for this, but it's a pretty simple interceptor  that can provide that behavior.

Comment: I am new to struts. Yes, as you said, when i have a GET method I just return the form and when i has a POST method I do my bussiness work. I there is an interceptor can do that. Please show me, Dave Newton.

Comment: Do you really need a *method* for viewing the form?

Comment: You may need one, yes, @AleksandrM. You may want to default some fields or perform some other logic.

Comment: Yes. There are some selectboxes that must get value from database. And i also use tiles plugin to view the page.

Comment: @StevenBenitez: Seems like OP is new to the framework. And there are other (better) possibilities how to populate form controls or perform some other logic.

Comment: So there are many comments and there isn't any answer to my question?

Comment: @hieund Your first code example, showing what you want, isn't even valid. You cannot define the same method signature multiple times (even if the annotations differ). Why not use different method names?

Comment: So there isn't any better way. I just want to use the same method name. If there is no way else, i must use two method name for display view (using tiles) and process form.